# bs4 HTML cleaner function with repetitive nested if clauses,

Tags: python, python-3.x, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[I made a little web-scraper that downloads the source html files as well. Now for the sake of saving storage space i wrote a small function to delete quite a bit of stuff in the html file (specific id's, classes and meta information as well as  footers, headers, and links).
The function takes the `html tree` as input and outputs the *shrunk* html to be saved on the machine.

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
tags = ['script', 'noscript', 'footer', 'header']

div_classes = ["head no-print", "col-md-6", "col-md-6 less-padding-left no-print",
               'col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 less-padding-left no-print',
               "col-sm-4 less-padding-left sidebar no-print hidden-xs",]
div_ids = ['navwrapper', 'citations']
links = ['stylesheet', 'text/css', 'canonical', 'alternate']
meta = ['metasummary', 'viewport', 'og_title', 'og_description']

def reduce_filesize(webcontent_string, output_file):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webcontent_string, features='lxml')

    # remove full tags
    for i in tags:
        for element in soup.find_all(i):
            element.decompose()

    # remove div's based on id
    for i in div_ids:
        for element in soup.find_all('div', {'id': i}):
            element.decompose()

    # remove div's based on class
    for i in div_classes:
        for element in soup.find_all('div', {'class': i}):
            element.decompose()

    # remove stylesheets and css
    for i in links:
        for element in soup.find_all('link', {'rel': i}):
            element.decompose()

    # removing meta text
    for i in meta:
        for element in soup.find_all('meta', {'id': i}):
            element.decompose()

    # remove comments
    comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
    for c in comments:
        c.extract()

    with open(output_file, "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
        file.close
```

Now what's bugging me is the repetition of the if statements with only slight changes each time. I've tried handling this by creating a `dict` of all the list and use that but couldn't get it to work. To make it faster I tried using list comprehension for the inner loops instead which works just fine but I'm certain it can be improved further.

Thank you for all input and advice!

[Here a link to a page to be shrunk](https://sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/01/200102143429.htm)

Comment: Can you share a testable html file with all implied "stuff" to be deleted?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I added a link, hope that works for you